# Json-server how to set a custom URL for the api

Tags: api, json-server

I am working on an app and used json-server for the backend api. I published the app using github pages and everything seemed to be working fine on my laptop. But when I try to open the app on another device, it does not work. I realized this was because I am using localhost:3001 as the resource for my api, and this only exists on my laptop. I am now trying to change the resource from localhost:3001 to a custom url 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM/movements'. The issue I'm running into now is that the POST, PATCH, and DELETE methods in my actions aren't updating the api anymore. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.